# Magento 2 zend error BarcodeRenderer.php

Tags: module, shipping, zend-framework, multishipping

Has anybody encountered this error before? I'm not even using temando nor is it enabled. I did try enabling it to see if that would fix it but no luck.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Barcode\Renderer\AbstractRenderer' not found in /srv/public_html/vendor/temando/module-shipping-m2/Model/Pickup/Pdf/BarcodeRenderer.php on line 22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you add this to your `composer.json` and run `composer install`

```
   "require": {
        [...]
    },
    "replace": {
        "temando/module-shipping-m2": "*",
    },
    "config": {
        [...]
```

That should remove extension and trigger a `composer dump-autoload`

But basically remove the unwanted extension

Without it in place I can't see any reason how it would continue to call `Zend\Barcode\Renderer\AbstractRenderer`

Source: my all time favourite blog post

https://www.integer-net.com/removing-unused-core-modules-from-magento-2-the-right-way/

Comment: Sorry for the late response @Dominic. I'm testing right now.